# Using Micronaut custom validation, AnnotationValue does not support Closures

Tags: groovy, annotations, micronaut

I am using Micronaut with Groovy, and I would like to introduce a custom validation called `@NotNullIf` used like this:

```
@Introspected
class Cust {
   @NotNull
   CustType type

   //  Only NotNull if CustType != NONE
   @NotNullIf({ Cust obj -> obj.type != CustType.NONE })
   String optional
}
```

My `@NotNullIf` annotation looks like this:

```
@Target([FIELD, METHOD])
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [])
@Documented
@interface NotNullIf {

    Class<? extends Closure<Boolean>> value()

    String message() default "validation.not.null.if.message"

    Class<?>[] groups() default []
}
```

And my `NotNullIfConstraint` is this:

```
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.NonNull
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable
import io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidator
import io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidatorContext
import jakarta.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Slf4j
class NotNullIfConstraint implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullIf, Object> {

    @Override
    boolean isValid(@Nullable Object value, @NonNull AnnotationValue<NotNullIf> annotationMetadata, @NonNull ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        Closure<Boolean> shouldEvaluateNotNull = annotationMetadata.get('value', Closure).orElseThrow { throw new IllegalArgumentException("NotNullIf missing value()") }

        boolean evaluateNotNull = shouldEvaluateNotNull.call(context.rootBean)

        return evaluateNotNull ? value != null : true
    }
}
```

What happens is, that I get an IllegalArgumentException throw, because it cannot find `value()` even though it's defined in the class that's being validated.

Is this a limitation on the `AnnotationValue` collector in Micronaut? Or am I missing a dependency?

Comment: Have you read the Defining Additional Constraints part here: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#beanValidation

Comment: @RoarS.Yes, that's I found the first example, but it seems that `AnnotationValue` discards the Closure type.